# Running script commands after SSH

Tags: shell, ssh

I need to write a script that will SSH into a remote host, then run certain commands on that remote host, then exit.  If I just do

```
ssh $host

#some command
```

the script will SSH in, wait until I manually exit, then run the commands.

How do I run those commands on the remote host?

Comment: You can also use fabric (http://fabfile.org)

Answer (score 21):

```
ssh $host 'command1; command2; command3'
```

or if you have just one command:

```
ssh $host command1
```

or if you have many commands (a script file):

```
cat file | ssh $host sh
```

Comment: how would we modify the third option if there are arguments that need to be passed?

Comment: I want to run a command when ssh successfully and still keep the connection so that I can do the other task, but with this solution, the connection auto close

Comment: @TrungNguyen: you can do something like: `ssh user@host.com -t 'cd /some/where; bash -l'`, but you can't do it directly

Answer (score 1):

This can be used too, if you have multiple servers.

```
for ((i=1; i <= 10; i++))
do
echo $i
ssh host$i << EOF
cd /somedir
command1;
command2;
EOF
done
```